# Windows Store App Webservice

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, windows-store-apps, webservice-client

I have made my first webservice but now I'am having trouble connecting to it.

In my visual studio I did add "Service Reference" and linked my site url to it.

Here on the picture: http://prntscr.com/3108bk , you can see under Service References my web server + you can see clearly that it has an operation

My problem is now that I cannot use it in my code.
The error I have is: are you missing a reference but I added it into my references!

http://prntscr.com/3108sm

If you have any idea how I can use this in my code, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found my error, I am trying to connect to my server but I have to make a client first.
But now I have to problem that I have no clue how to make that client

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426532/how-to-make-client-web-service